# Find for Exact Match and then Replace MySQl Query

Tags: mysql

i want to replace A to APPLE and E to Elephant

when i ran 1st query it is replacing A to APPLE and then when i am running again it is replacing

E to Elephant and APPLE TO APPLELEPHANT (apple has e at the end) but i didn't want to do this

**table1 (mysql table)**

```
CODE 

A    
E
C
```

when i run this update table1 set code = replace(code, 'A', 'APPLE');

it is converting as

```
CODE 

APPLE    
E
C
```

it is OK!

and when i ran this update table1 set code = replace(code, 'E', 'ELEPHANT');

```
CODE 

APPLELEPHANT    
ELEPHANT
C
```

APPLE IS ALSO CONVERTING i don't want like this

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL can only replace one string at a time, so you're going to run into this problem anyway. If you're fetching the data in PHP, you can then replace the strings with [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) by passing an array of strings as a parameter. (Note that, even though `str_replace` also allows using arrays of substrings, it is subject to the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

If you strings only contain alphabetic characters, you can take an "intermediate" approach:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(code, 'A', '1'), 'E', '2), '1', 'Apple'), '2', 'Elephant)
from table1
```

Of course, this will not work if you have 1s and 2s in the values.  So, you can instead move to other characters, such as $, %, ^, & *, and so on.

In a sense, my idea solution would be to delimit each character, to turn the initial string into something like:

```
<A>
<E>
<C>
```

Then to do:

```
select replace(replace(eplace(replace(newcode, '<A>', 'Apple'), '<E>', 'Elephant'), '<', ''), '>', '')
```

If your code is really a single character, then you can take an approach like this.